# Batch find and replace filename in file with a loop

Tags: regex, bash

I'm on windows (but I eventually can run a virtual linux) and I'm trying to replace some lines in multiple *python* Ren'Py files when I call my image or music files in them

I mean actually, in my Ren'Py files, I have: `imagebutton "aaaa.png"` and I would like to replace it with `imagebutton "images/aaaa.png"`
And I would like to do it with all the files in another folder since I moved all my 7500 images in an /images/ folder now

Actually, my folders are like that:

```
script1.rpy
script2.rpy
/images/aaaa.png
/images/bbbb.png
```

I found that:

```sh
find -name '*.png' -printf '%f\n' |
while read file; do
    # do something with "$file"
done 

while read a; do
    echo ${a//abc/XYZ}
done < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/file.txt.t
mv /tmp/file.txt{.t,}
```

But I really don't know how to combine it :(

Comment: Do you want to replace the file contents with the actual file path?

Comment: Yes I would like to change in my python file the file pathof all my images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I decided to do it in Python

```py
import os
import sys

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

scripts = [s for s in listdir(sys.argv[1]) if isfile(join(sys.argv[1], s)) and "rpy" == s.split(".")[1]]
folders = ["images", "sounds"]
warning = []

for script in scripts:
    print(script)
    file = open(script, "r", encoding="utf8")
    content = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    for folder in folders:
        folderContent = [i for i in listdir(sys.argv[1] + os.sep + folder) if isfile(join(sys.argv[1] + os.sep + folder, i))]

        for fc in folderContent:
            for i, e in enumerate(content):
                if fc in e:
                    if len(e.split("/")) > 1:
                        warning.append(script + " | ligne " +  str(i+1))

                    content[i] = content[i].replace(fc, folder + "/" + fc)

    file = open(script, "w", encoding="utf8")
    file.write("".join(content))
    file.close()

file = open("warningRename.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
file.write("\n".join(warning))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace imagebutton "aaaa.png" with imagebutton "images/aaaa.png", it is as below:

```sh
while read a; do
  echo ${a//imagebutton \"/imagebutton \"images\/}
done < /tmp/file.txt
```

Another way, there is a way to use associative arrays in Bash.
However, I have not confirmed whether it works with many files.

```sh
declare -A files
for file in `find -name '*.png'`; do
    name=`basename $file`;
    files[$name]=${file#./};
done
while read a; do
  from=`echo $a | grep -o -E "[^\"]+\.png"`
  echo ${a//$from/${files[$from]}}
done < /tmp/file.txt
```

I think taht it is better to be written in Python if you can use Python.